# Any concerns about Windows Server 2016 to build out a new SharePoint 2016 farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, windows-server

I want to build a new SharePoint 2016 medium sized farm using the new MinRole farm topology. I am planning to use:

```
- 2 servers for Front-End with Distributed Cache
- 1 server for Application plus Search
- 1 server for External (SQL Server)
```

I don't see any articles (TechNet or other) about using Windows Server 2016, and only Windows Server 2012 R2 is mentioned. Does that mean Windows Server 2016 is yet supported for SP2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2016 is fully supported with SharePoint server 2016.
You can read this Technet Article.[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#section4)
here is the extract from it.

> Minimum requirements for SharePoint servers in a farm One of the
>   following server operating systems:
>    Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard or
>   Datacenter
>   Windows Server 2016 Standard or Datacenter

I have installed the SharePoint 2016 on Windows server 2016 without any issue so far.

Comment: Does SQL Server (the databases for SharePoint( get a Custom role, as per MinRole classification?

Comment: No, Sharepoint does not install anything on the SQL server.SQL is only hosting SharePoint DBs, their are some best practice, we have to follow for best performance on SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As per MSDN SharePoint supports Windows server 2016 Standard or Data Center.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx

Here is an article about Farm Topology.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt743704(v=office.16).aspx